# How to avoid reflected dots?

Tags: customization

I want to ask if there is a way to keep the same values, but avoid this light dot as shown in my picture below. I am using principal BSFD and using point light. I also tried to smooth by simplify and decrease light bouncing, but it didn't work.

[image: screenshot of Blender with the light dot on a sphere highlighted]

Comment: That dot is a reflection of the light source. Without doing non-physical things, the only ways to make it go away are make the surface rougher (more diffuse) or change the light source. Perhaps it would help to know why you want to do this?

Comment: gandalf3's right, but in addition, this is somewhere (a sharp lighting border) where messing with color management settings in scene/properties would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the lamps reflection in glossy materials. This will hide the reflection of the light source in glossy surfaces.

Select the light source, go to the "object tab". Under "cycles settings" remove the checkmark in "Glossy"[image]

Comment: You can also increase the size of the point lamp. Depending on distance to object, a size of 0.2 can give a small lit area while a size of 8.0 will give a more even light over the whole object. You may also want to increase the strength with the larger size.